# My project is crashed because of my fault

Tags: android, android-resources, unresolved-external

i was working on swipe and tabs in my project then i decide to use sherlock but i changed it to google support api and did it. it worked fine.

but when i removing sherlock from the library in project properties and some other places My project is crashed.

it show the packages such as a folder which fixed from "Build Path" > "Use as Source Folder".

but the errors still available.

the errors is for Resource part of project that i can't fix that.

Errors:
R.layout.main       >   R cannot be resolved to a variable

in other activities:

com.example.project.R   >   The import com.example.project.R cannot be resolved

thanks and i apologies for my bad english.

Comment: Post activity's imports and your package name.

Comment: There would be a problem with one of your resource XML files (Possibly your manifest), that would cause the R file not to build.

Comment: Very thank for your time guys, the problem is solved. I just replaced the ".classpath" file of other project with the this project's same file and every thing is ok.